# First time deploying rails app, cant get passenger to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

Used railsready, then passenger w/ apache2, finally copied my app to /home/myapp.

Inserted the passenger config lines into /etc/apache2/apache.conf at the bottom along with my virtual host settings:

The servers name is rails.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7
PassengerRuby /home/myapp/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName rails
    DocumentRoot /home/myapp/public
</VirtualHost>
```

All I get is the apache "It Works" page when I open the IP address. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you forgot to copy in the passenger's config too.

Comment: I did, the load module, PassengerRoot, PassengerRuby lines. Put them right above the virtual host lines

Comment: they didn't seem to make it into your question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a `ServerName` so you must use it to access this VirtualHost (and not the IP address as you mentioned). Connect to http://rails/

For this to work, the hostname `rails` must resolv to your server's IP. You can add it to you [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) or use a real domain name configured to resolve to this IP.

Or you can change the `DocumentRoot` of the default `VirtualHost` of Apache, and then it will always respond with the Rails app.

Comment: yep changing the default worked. Now I have a paperclip error to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName rails
  DocumentRoot /home/myapp/public
  <Directory /var/www/robox/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, you might need to disable the *default site*. In Ubuntu you can do this with:

```
[sudo] a2dissite default
[sudo] service apache2 restart
```

Comment: OK. The next thing is: it might not be matching on the `ServerName`. What do you type in the browser exactly to access this app?

Comment: Firefox, I am getting this error. But it is resolving to the IP. apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using THE_IP for ServerName

Comment: No, what do you *type* in the browser's location bar to access the app. Is it `http://rails` ?

Comment: Also that message from apache2 tells me that it is not mapping the name `rails` to the server. What OS are you running on?

Comment: See @michael-witrant's answer above

Comment: OK. The configuration above **only** matches to `http://rails` so check out @michael-witrant's answer for your options :)